# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:54568

Tags: c#-4.0, webclient, system.net.sockets, webclient.uploaddata

The following error started coming up suddenly! It worked for months after the application was deployed on the server but suddenly it has stopped working and showing the following error.

The code I am using as follows:

```html
private void PostData()
{
  c.Add("publicid", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
  c.Add("name", "ABC");
  c.Add("label:Affiliate_ID", "207");
  c.Add("website", "websitename.com");
  c.Add("label:IP_Address", Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
  c.Add("firstname", txtFirstName.Text.Trim());
  c.Add("phone", txtPhone.Text.Trim());
  c.Add("lastname", txtLastName.Text.Trim());
  c.Add("email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
  c.Add("label:Date_of_Birth", String.Format("{0:YYYY-MM-DD}", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDob.Text.Trim())));
  c.Add("lane", txtStreetAddress.Text.Trim());
  c.Add("code", txtZip.Text.Trim());
  c.Add("city", txtCity.Text.Trim());
  c.Add("Province", txtProvince.Text.Trim());
  c.Add("label:Time_At_Address", stay.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
  c.Add("label:Known_Credit_Issues", "yes");
  c.Add("label:Net_Monthly_Income", txtMothlyIncome.Text.Trim());
  c.Add("label:Occupation", txtOccopation.Text.Trim());
  c.Add("label:Employer_Name", txtEmployer.Text.Trim());
  c.Add("label:Employment_Length", "");
  c.Add("label:Bankruptcy", "No");
  c.Add("label:Employer_Phone_Number", "");
  c.Add("label:Employer_Postal_Code", "");
  c.Add("label:Employer_Province", "");
  c.Add("label:Employer_City", "");
  c.Add("label:Employer_Address", "");

  var myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
  const string postingUrl = "https://xxxx.com/modules/Webforms/capture.php";

  byte[] responseArray = null;
  responseArray = myWebClient.UploadValues(postingUrl, "POST", c);
  var responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
}
```

[image]

Please help! It is a live application :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: download Fiddler which will help you see what is happening when you make your request - http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark and say that a system-wide proxy has been set on your server and since `WebClient` instances use that by default, it's now failing.

After:

```
var myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
```

Add:

```
myWebClient.Proxy = null;
```

Recompile/restart the app and let me know if my voodoo debugging sense was right or utter BS.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I added the fix and restarted the app. Now the page is taking too long to respond after I POST and finally ends up saying "The connection was reset"

Comment: @NiladriSarkar that means it's definitely proxy related, does the server use a proxy to communicate over the internet? check if that proxy is down.

Comment: I will put this to my client and let you know what he says. But thank you so much for the valuable information. At least now I can see some light

Comment: Got his response. He says there is no proxy set up on the server.